# Zend_Search_Luncene handle Querys

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-search-lucene

iam trying to implement an Searchmachine into my site. Iam using Zend_Search_Lucene for this.

The index is created like this :

```
public function  create($config, $create = true)
{
    $this->_config = $config;

    // create a new index
    if ($create) {
        Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
            new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive()
        );

        $this->_index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create(APPLICATION_PATH . $this->_config->index->path);
    } else {
        $this->_index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(APPLICATION_PATH . $this->_config->index->path);
    }
}
```

{

```
public function addToIndex($data)   
   $i = 0;

    foreach ($data as $val) {
        $scriptObj = new Sl_Model_Script();
        $scriptObj->title = $val['title'];
        $scriptObj->description = $val['description'];
        $scriptObj->link = $val['link'];
        $scriptObj->tutorials = $val['tutorials'];
        $scriptObj->screenshot = $val['screenshot'];
        $scriptObj->download = $val['download'];
        $scriptObj->tags = $val['tags'];
        $scriptObj->version = $val['version'];
        $this->_dao->add($scriptObj);
        $i++;
    }

    return $i;
}


 /**
     * Add to Index
     *
     * @param Sl_Interface_Model $scriptObj
     */
    public function add(Sl_Interface_Model $scriptObj)
    {

        // UTF-8 for INDEX

        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('title', $scriptObj->title, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('tags', $scriptObj->tags, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('version', $scriptObj->version, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('download', $scriptObj->download, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('link', $scriptObj->link));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('description', $scriptObj->description, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('tutorials', $scriptObj->tutorials, 'utf-8'));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('screenshot', $scriptObj->screenshot));
        $this->_index->addDocument($doc);

    }
```

But when i try to query the index with :

$index->find('Wordpress 2.8.1' . '*');

im getting the following error :

**"non-wildcard characters are required at the beginning of pattern."**

any ideas how to query for a string like mine ? an query for "wordpress" works like excepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene cannot handle leading wildcards, only trailing ones. That is, it does not support queries like 'tell me everyone whose name ends with 'att'' which would be something like

first_name: *att

It only supports trailing wildcards. Tell me everyone whose names *end* that start with 'ma'

first_name: ma*

See this Lucene FAQ entry:

http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-4d62118417eaef0dcb87f4370583f809848ea695

There IS a workaround for Lucene 2.1 but the developers say it can be "expensive".

Comment: No, you could query for multiple words with trailing prefixes, let say you wanted to find all documents that start with "kine" or "dict" you would do:

name: kine* OR name: dict*

Basically just OR the clauses together.

Does that answer your question?